# How to pass parameter to ComboBox ItemsSource binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am working with WPF for the first time, so please bear with me.

I have a combobox, which is meant to generically display some lookup data. The models for the different types of lookups are exactly the same, just different data sources which are retrieved via a single method call passing different enumerations to control the returned data set. Fairly simple stuff.

```
public sealed class MyDataProvider
{
   public enum Types
   {
      Green,
      Blue,
      Orange
   }

   private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ObservableCollection<LookUpVm>> _lookupData =
      new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ObservableCollection<LookUpVm>>();

   private static readonly Lazy<MyDataProvider> lazy =
      new Lazy<MyDataProvider>(() => new MyDataProvider());

   public static MyDataProvider Instance => lazy.Value;

   private MyDataProvider()
   {
   }

   public ObservableCollection<LookUpVm> GreenLookupDataSource => GetLookupDataSource(Types.Green);

   public ObservableCollection<LookUpVm> GetLookupDataSource(Types lookupEnum)
   {
      ObservableCollection<LookUpVm> lookupDataSource;
      if (_lookupData.TryGetValue(lookupEnum, out lookupDataSource))
         return lookupDataSource;

      lookupDataSource = new ObservableCollection<LookUpVm>();
      var returnedlookupDataSource =
         SomeMasterSource.GetlookupDataSourceBylookupEnum(lookupEnum).OrderBy(ia => ia.Name);

      foreach (var returnedLookupData in returnedlookupDataSource)
      {
         lookupDataSource.Add(returnedLookupData);
      }
      _lookupData.TryAdd(lookupEnum, lookupDataSource);

      return lookupDataSource;
   }
}
```

This works great for the 0th iteration, where I create a GreenLookupComboBox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static objectDataProviders:MyDataProvider.Instance}, 
          Path=GreenLookupDataSource}" />
```

However, what I really need to be able to do is to set up a combobox which can have its Types enum value set on the parent View, which would then call directly to the GetLookupDataSource and pass the enum. We have several dozen lookup types, and defining a new property for each feels less than ideal. Something like the below for the control view...

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static objectDataProviders:MyDataProvider.Instance}, 
          Path=GetLookupDataSource}" />
```

And something like the below for where I use the lookup control.

```
<local:MyLookupControl Type=Types.Green />
```

Is this even possible?

EDIT:

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have two key-value pairs of lists.

ListOne

1 - A

2 - B

3 - C

and

ListTwo

1 - X

2 - Y

3 - Z

They are accessible by calling the method GetList(Enum.LookupType). They share the same ViewModel and View. However, I need to place both of them on a form for my users to select from.

I'm looking for some way to use XAML like the following on the View they appear on.

```
<local:MyLookupControl Method=GetList Parameter=Enum.ListOne/>
<local:MyLookupControl Method=GetList Parameter=Enum.ListTwo />
```

This should display a pair of comboboxes, one bound to ListOne and one bound to ListTwo.

Comment: Easiest way to do this is give your viewmodel a Types property that just returns Enum.GetValues(typeof(Types)), a Type SelectedType property, and a SelectedTypeValues property that returns `GetLookupDataSource(SelectedType)`. You could factor out those three properties into a child viewmodel `EnumCollectionThingy<TEnum>`

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially just trying to set up databinding on a couple controls. This is simple then so long as you have the correct datacontext for the view.

Controls can be bound to properties (which is exactly what you are looking for).

Using your edited example here is how you would do that:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _listOne;
private ObservableCollection<string> _listTwo;
private string _selectedListOneItem;
private string _selectedListTwoItem;

public ObservableCollection<string> ListOne
{
    get { return _listOne; }
    set { _listOne = value; }
}

public ObservableCollection<string> ListTwo
{
    get { return _listTwo; }
    set { _listTwo = value; }
}

public string SelectedListOneItem
{
    get { return _selectedListOneItem; }
    set { _selectedListOneItem = value; }
}

public string SelectedListTwoItem
{
    get { return _selectedListTwoItem; }
    set { _selectedListTwoItem = value; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOne}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListOneItem}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListTwo}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListTwoItem}"/>
```

You have several options in how you want to load or get your lists. You can either load them in the constructor or for something a bit heavier is load them every time you "get" in the property. I would recommend loading those in the constructor.

What I provided is basically autoprops and can even be further simplified but I wanted to show you that you can also write code in the getter and setter of those properties to further expand on the items. For instance, you may want something on the background to fire off when SelectedListOneItem changes. In this case on the SET of SelectedListOneItem you can set the value but then also run a method/function which may update other properties.

WPF is very dependent on properties to bind between ViewModels and Views. In your response before the edit you are using fields which can't be bound to controls in a view.

EDIT:
If you do plan on updating properties in the ViewModel that would change things on the view you are also going to want to look into INotifyPropertyChanged. By implementing INotifyPropertyChanged the view will be updated/notified when properties are changing. INotifyPropertyChanged comes with it's own event that you must invoke in the setting of a property. Here is also a very helpful method you can call that will fire this event for you much easier.

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

You call this like so:

```
public string SelectedListOneItem
{
    get { return _selectedListOneItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedListOneItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

That way if anything else in the ViewModel updates SelectedListOneItem that your view will make the appropriate change. In this case it would make the combobox select the new value you set in SelectedListOneItem.